# XSD restriction and enumeration using only locally defined types?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have XML where I want to have attributes and restriction to the simple element account-no at the same time as

```
  <bank-cheque>
    <cheque-no>2345</cheque-no>
    <issue-date>2015-11-19</issue-date>
    <cheque-issued-for>john</cheque-issued-for>
    <account-no account-type="saving">sanjauli</account-no> <!-- This one here
        account-type is an enumeration having ( saving , current) and values are
        ( sanjauli , summerhill, dhalli ) -->
  </bank-cheque>
```

and I perfectly wrote an XSD for this as

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bank-cheque" type="bank-cheque-type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="bank-cheque-type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="cheque-no" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="issue-date" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="cheque-issued-for" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="account-no" type="accountNoType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="accountNoType1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="saving"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="current"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="corporate"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="accountNoType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="BranchType">
                <xs:attribute name="account-type" type="accountNoType1" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="BranchType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="sanjauli"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="summer hill"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="dhalli"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

and everything is working fine, but now I want to write this XSD using anonymous tag approach .. 
My question is : Can I write it using anonymous approach or not ?

Comment: *anonymous tag approach*:   Please define.  Do you mean you'd like to use `xsd:any`?

Comment: from anonymous approach i mean something like this one :-->   <xs:element name="x"><xs:comlexType></complexType> ... i'e anonymous complex types without having any name, i don't know what is the name of this approach , but i do know that there are two ways of writting an xsd and this  is the another one...

Comment: Ah, I see.  No, you can't totally eliminate named, global type references while extending and restricting like that, but you can reduce your global type reference count [down to one...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33678824/290085)

Comment: But generally speaking, using named global types makes them reusable so the only real benefit of anonymous types is that it saves you a bit of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot totally eliminate references to global definitions when extending and restricting.   This is as close as you can get:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="bank-cheque">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cheque-no" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="issue-date" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:element name="cheque-issued-for" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="account-no">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="BranchType">
                <xs:attribute name="account-type" use="required">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:enumeration value="saving"/>
                      <xs:enumeration value="current"/>
                      <xs:enumeration value="corporate"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="BranchType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="sanjauli"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="summer hill"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="dhalli"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**Update:** To set a default value for `account-type`, you'll have to make it optional.  Then you can specify the default value via a `default` attribute on `xs:attribute`:

```
            <xs:attribute name="account-type" default="saving">
```

Comment: now, for branchType i want any one enumeration to be default. what should i do ?

Comment: You can use `xs:attribute/@default` as I've shown in the updated answer.